# Docker RailsのCORS設定について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nuxt.js, axios

フロントエンド(Nuxt)からaxiosでAPI(Rails)にアクセスする際、CORSエラーになってしまい、RailsのCORSをどのように設定すれば良いか悩んでいます。

下記のソースコードの通り、いくつか試してみたのですが、同様のCORSエラーでした。
こういった場合はやはり、コンテナのIPを固定すべきでしょうか？
ご教授いただけると助かります。

ブラウザ エラー

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/xxx' from origin 'http://localhost:7000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

## ソースコード

api_rails/config/initializers/cors.rb

```rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'Nuxtのコンテナ名', 'localhost', 'localhost:5000', '127.0.0.1', '0.0.0.0', '0.0.0.0:5000'

    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end
```

nuxt.conf.js

```js
axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://api_rails:5000/api/',
    browserBaseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/',
}
```

## 環境

Railsコンテナ外部ポート 5000
Railsコンテナ内部ポート 3000

Nuxtコンテナ外部ポート 7000
Nuxtコンテナ内部ポート 3000

サーバホストはどちらも0.0.0.0で起動

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross Originはscheme, host, portのいずれか一つでも異なる場合にその扱いになります。
サーバー側はhttp://localhost:7000に対して、クライアント側(ブラウザ)はhttp://localhost:5000です。
schemeはhttp、hostはlocalhost、portは5000と7000でportが異なることからCross Originの扱いになります。これを許可するにはrails側でlocalhost:5000のoriginからの通信を許可する必要があります。これに関してはrailsのoriginsに指定されているので問題ありません。これ以外の記述は不要でしょう。

今回問題になってるのはaxiosのbase URLです。dockerのホストからdockerにアクセスするとき、docker内部の名前解決は利用できないので、ブラウザから見たrails側のhostはlocalhost:5000を指定する必要があります。次のような設定になると思います。

```js
axios: {
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000/api/',
  browserBaseURL: 'http://localhost:5000/api/',
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
接続できました。
わかりやすく大変助かりました。